# JavaScript HTML5 CSS3 project template in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, css, visual-studio-2013

I've just downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web and I want to know how I can deploy JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3 only projects?

I can't find a suitable template or way to do it. I already searched for JavaScript templates online, but still unsuccessful. I've even tried to download Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows 8.

Does anyone know how I can solve it and start developing for web using VS2013 Express?

Comment: I didn't tell you that I'm not planning, but at this point I'm interested only in pure `JS/HTML5/CSS3` because I'm looking forward to take a `MS Exam 70-480`. I've reading `Study Guide` and it recommends VS environment so that's why I've decided to give it a try. I personally use `Sublime Text` as an IDE.

Comment: I see. I don't think there's a template or project type that will have just front-end stuff as a standard. Maybe have a look for online templates?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Obviously yes. I've searched online for VS2013 Express for Web and for Windows as well.

Comment: Couldn't find any? I mean, have you tried on `VS` itself, where you can look for online templates to download?

Comment: Because to start a new `MVC` project, even if it's blank, will add a lot of stuff you won't need.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Sure I've did. http://prntscr.com/4v3dfq. I've tried different templates as well but I can agree with you there is a lot of different thing which I will never use in my projects and that's why I'm here looking for a solution.

Comment: I had a look around and couldn't find a single one to suggest.

Comment: Actually I've found this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2013/04/10/how-can-i-create-pure-client-side-web-apps-using-html5-css3-and-javascript-using-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: And this one: https://wecodez.com/threads/pure-html-project-template-for-visual-studio.348/

Comment: @MelanciaUK I've also seen these 2 links, but unfortunately I've search online for `Windows Store app development` and `PureHTML` is just simply do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully, I've found a good blog post and download link for this `Pure HTML5/JS/CSS3 project template`.
I've spent a lot of time today, searching a solution how to start a pure project without useless things which I never use in future. Finally, I found download link for `purehtml` (codepen official link is no longer exist) in [article](http://www.antonoffplus.com/pure-html5-javascript-css3-visual-studio-2013-project-template/)

Update 17-Mar-15:

[Uploaded it to the dropbox, because previous link is stopped working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/js4ejt6t0s00qaa/PureHTMLVSTemplate.zip?dl=0)

Comment: The Zip file produced an error when extracting: "location directory mis-match for file css/"

Comment: Direct download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/afueuxxgenhum07/PureHTMLVSTemplate.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0):

the article link works for me, however, your provided zip does not. Your zip looks like it's damaged/corrupted. I get a CRC error on every file in it that I attempt to extract. 
[PureHTMLVSTemplate.jpg Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7B77.jpg)

however, this was a good guide I found while googling "visual studio 2015 html5 css3 website project template"

HOW TO CREATE HTML5 WEBSITE AND PAGE TEMPLATES FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2010
http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/21/how-to-create-html5-website-and-page-templates-for-visual-studio-2010/

I'm not sure how that helps me, as I'm using vs studio 2015 enterprise edition. Better than nothing, I suppose.