# Using Javascript like Visual Basic

Tags: javascript, cmd

I've been recently learning JavaScript and although I know it's intended for website use, I was wondering if you could create a pure JS application and run it in CMD. E.g. when you code in Visual Basic and execute it, it runs it in the CMD for you to work with. Is there a way I can do this with JS (I'm trying to make a text-based adventure if that makes it clearer as to why I want it in CMD)

any help given is appreciated!

-HugoNumber1

Comment: Look at node.js or rhino interpreter.

Comment: I can suggest a template to use. [JavaScript HTML5 CSS3 project template for Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314174/javascript-html5-css3-project-template-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: It actually I doesn't make it any clear why you would want it in CMD... you could do a textarea on a webpage..

Comment: Windows can be scripted using JScript. Google for Windows Scripting Host or Active Scripting. JScript is Microsoft's name for ECMAscript (known as Javascript on other platforms).

Comment: @BrettCaswell true, you can do it through a webpage, however, having a pure JS text-based adventure slows down the speed of a webpage along with the fact that the webpage will be useless as JS dialog takes main priority.

Comment: and to my previous notion.. are you intending for your  'players' to use their Command-Line Consoles to interact on?

Comment: Well, kind of, more of a "console" to give a nostalgic sense of feeling but for now a CMD will do

Comment: You may want to see the experience of those in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ..